# Where to find river flow time series for rivers in Europe?

Tags: data-request, europe, time-series

I am looking for river flow gauged data for rivers in Europe, i.e. time series.

Data can be peak flow or daily flow (m<sup>3</sup>/s) but it has to cover all  of Europe's river basins.

Comment: We're spoiled over here across the pond with the USGS aren't we...

Comment: Partial answer: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/9142/15414

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this website and it is the best solution so far:

http://www.bafg.de/GRDC/EN/02_srvcs/21_tmsrs/riverdischarge_node.html

Comment: Is that a question? Then edit it into your question and remove this 'answer'. If it's an answer give it some body: [Tell what it is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276628/189029) and use a proper link title (that's: [title](URL))

Answer (score 1):

For all of Europe, some useful links can be found at the Europe Environment Agency's [Trends in monthly stream flow - Projected change in average annual and seasonal river flow - Projected change in daily average river flow](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/indicators/river-flow-1)

Complete Dutch data can be found from Rijkswaterstaat's [Waterways page](https://www.rijkswaterstaat.nl/english/waterways/index.aspx).